# Angular2 click and ngIF

Tags: angular

I want to use `(click)` function only when `ngIF` have value `True`.

```
<tbody class="table-hover domains">
    <tr *ngFor="let domain of domains" (click)="gotoDetail(domain.id)">
        <td class="col-md-3">{{ domain.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ domain.validated }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So I need to add `ngIF` in `<tr>` tag as if `{{ domain.validated }}` value is `True`, then `(click)` function works, else it don't work or show message that variable have value `False`. How to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<tbody class="table-hover domains">
  <tr *ngFor="let domain of domains" (click)="!domain.validated || gotoDetail(domain.id)">
  <td class="col-md-3">{{ domain.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ domain.validated }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Hope it will work for you .

The function will only be called if first part(!domain.validated) will return false.

Comment: It works, thanks, so I can check value for True/False in (click) function, great.

Comment: happy to know , that it worked for you. Yes you can check true/false inside the click

Comment: @Trimidas you can accept the answer if it worked for you.

Comment: I'm wondering, is this supposed to work ? Can we use a ternary operator instead ?

Comment: yes you can use ternary operator inside like `(click)="condition? gotoDetail(domain.id):gotoedit(domain.id)"`

 , but for suggestion call one method and inside that method use condition , that will be more readable.

Comment: This answer with ternary operator is much better in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a second parameter, Boolean, to the the goToDetail function and redirect the user only if it's true.

Comment: Wouldn't it just hide all inside of tag if ngIF will be false?

Comment: Yes i read your question to fast, working on a more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<tbody class="table-hover domains">
  <template ngFor let-domain [ngForOf]="domains ">
  <tr *ngIf="domain.validated" (click)="gotoDetail(domain.id)">
    <td class="col-md-3">{{ domain.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ domain.validated }}</td>
  </tr>
  </template>
</tbody>
```

You can use `ng-template` also.

Comment: In your code and way you using ngIf it hides <tr> tag if domain.validated is false. At least when I just checked it, it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your function like this:

```
gotoDetail(id: number){
    if (this.domain.validated)
    // Your normal code
    else 
    // Display error message, Do nothing
}
```